# Perform matrix subtraction

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of list, let's say

```
a=[
[2,3,4],
[1,5,2]
]
b=[
[1,4,2],
[0,1,3]
]
```

And I want to perform a-b such that

```
a-b=[
[1,-1,2],
[1,4,-1]
]
```

Then I want to add all elements in the list such that `sum(a-b)=6`

Whats the best way of doing this?

Comment: Not my downvote, but you might want to add your current code to the question.

Comment: I don't understand the close reason. The question is very narrowly scoped; it's simply asking how to subtract two matrices. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Make them NumPy arrays, array math like this is exactly what the NumPy library is for.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([
[2,3,4],
[1,5,2]
]
)
b=np.array([
[1,4,2],
[0,1,3]
]
)

c = a-b

sumc = np.sum(c)
```